# Installing Django on MAC error msg "Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-2yOWor/django/"

Tags: python, django, macos, python-2.7

I am trying to install Django 2.0 on my Macbook on Sierra 10.12.6, with Python 2.7.14 using virtualenv but I keep getting this error code at the bottom:

(sorry in advance, I'm new here so not sure how to make it more user-friendly to read so also attached a screenshot below)

```
Joeys-MBP:somename joeybaloney$ pip install django
Collecting django
  Using cached Django-2.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/wj/jbbqxb5d6ld9q00gw73mjzp00000gn/T/pip-build-QicGdd/django/setup.py", line 32, in <module>
        version = __import__('django').get_version()
      File "django/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
        from django.utils.version import get_version
      File "django/utils/version.py", line 61, in <module>
        @functools.lru_cache()
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'lru_cache'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/wj/jbbqxb5d6ld9q00gw73mjzp00000gn/T/pip-build-QicGdd/django/
```

I've tried almost every solution here on Stackoverflow such as updating tools, using sudo pip install but nothing seems to work.

Terminal screenshot: [image]

Answer (score 6):

Django 2.0 dropped support for python 2.

> Django 2.0 supports Python 3.4, 3.5, and 3.6. We highly recommend and
>   only officially support the latest release of each series.

so you can use 1.11 the LTS django version and it will work just fine,It will be long supported till at least April 2020. [Django Roadmap](https://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2015/jun/25/roadmap/)

```
pip install django==1.11.8
```

> The Django 1.11.x series is the last to support Python 2.7.

or install python3 and use pip3 or virtualenv with python3 then install django 2.0

Both of the quotes are from [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/2.0/#python-compatibility)